# ActiveMQ on Ubuntu 12.04 reports "not running" but it is running and listening to it's port... why could that be?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, queue

I installed ActiveMQ on Ubuntu using the command `sudo apt-get install activemq` which seemed to work fine.

Then, I activated a configuration by copying the sample configuration provided with the installation with this command:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/activemq/instances-available/main /etc/activemq/instances-enabled/main
```

And then I started the broker:
    sudo service activemq start

Which seemed to work since it returned an OK and no errors.

I can see it is started and listening to port 61616:

```
administrator@ci-server:~/tmp/Codebase/Build/com.specktro.orchid.build$ netstat -an | grep 61616
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:61616         :::*                    LISTEN
```

Also, if I start it in debug mode, I can see it runs fine:

```
administrator@ci-server:~/tmp/Codebase/Build/com.specktro.orchid.build$ sudo /etc/init.d/activemq console main
 * Starting with Console ActiveMQ instance  main                                                                                   INFO: Loading '/usr/share/activemq/activemq-options'
INFO: Using java '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'
INFO: Starting in foreground, this is just for debugging purposes (stop process by pressing CTRL+C)
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_25 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
  Heap sizes: current=126720k  free=123924k  max=253440k
    JVM args: -Xms128M -Xmx256M -Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dactivemq.classpath=/var/lib/activemq/main/conf;/etc/activemq/instances-enabled/main; -Dactivemq.home=/usr/share/activemq -Dactivemq.base=/var/lib/activemq/main
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /usr/share/activemq
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /var/lib/activemq/main
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
 INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@44edb080: startup date [Sun Nov 17 16:03:30 PST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
 INFO | PListStore:/var/lib/activemq/main/data/localhost/tmp_storage started
 INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/var/lib/activemq/main/data/kahadb]
 INFO | JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
 INFO | KahaDB is version 3
 INFO | Recovering from the journal ...
 INFO | Recovery replayed 1 operations from the journal in 0.029 seconds.
 INFO | ActiveMQ 5.5.0 JMS Message Broker (localhost) is starting
 INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org/
 INFO | Listening for connections at: tcp://localhost:61616
 INFO | Connector openwire Started
 INFO | ActiveMQ JMS Message Broker (localhost, ID:ci-server-47748-1384733012178-0:1) started
```

The problem is, when I run `activemq status`, it displays the following message:

```
administrator@ci-server:~/tmp/Codebase/Build/com.specktro.orchid.build$ activemq status
INFO: Loading '/usr/share/activemq/activemq-options'
INFO: Using java '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'
ActiveMQ not running
```

I have a script that checks for the output of this command, and it is failing on this because it expects the output to say that it is running... I can't change that script.

**Anyone knows why could this be?**

Any ideas on why would ActiveMQ report Not Running when it seems to be running would be greatly appreciated! I don't know what else to check...

Thank you very much!!

Eduardo

Answer (score 0):

I'm just fumbling my way through ActiveMQ on Debian Wheezy.  I couldn't understand what was happening with the apt-get install version either...

I have it running though.  I finally went with wget.  I create an activemq user, and as this user, I run:
  wget http://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/activemq/apache-activemq/5.10-SNAPSHOT/apache-activemq-5.10-20140603.133406-78-bin.tar.gz

When I untar, cd apache-activemq-5.10-SNAPSHOT
then I run ./bin/activemq start.

There's lots more to learn, but I've gotten that far.